# How does a self-cleaning dripping hose work?

Tags: watering, irrigation, hoses

How does the self-cleaning function of a dripping hose work?

Comment: I am not sure what a self cleaning dripping hose is.  Can you show us a picture or link to the product?

Comment: It's probably some marketing gimmick

Comment: Do you mean a soaker hose?  Or something for drip irrigation at the base of plants?

Comment: Something for drip water at the base of plants in the garden

Comment: On page 4 you can see one https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.baywa.de/fileadmin/user_upload/coverflow/Tropfbewaesserung_2013_kpl__klein_27.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjPqP-DoZ_MAhVEVxQKHfkMBsEQFghAMAQ&usg=AFQjCNF-5IQW7UQQuoo1HH-oU2KXMrGhEA&sig2=nMI-w0HHrXXPlXJlDtvutg

Answer (score 2):

By flushing [debris as it is detected throughout operation, and not only at the beginning or end of a cycle; this ensures uninterrupted dripper operation.](http://www.netafim.com/product/technet-)  It has a [labyrinth structure (Turbonet™) and anti-siphon mechanism](http://blog.netafim.com/dripper-clogging-problems-not-with-netafim/), covered by patents. They say:

> There are several algorithms built into the little dripper, ensuring that:
>
> - Pressure regulating mechanism ensures that each dripper provides the    same flow, regardless of inlet pressure.
> - Each dripper has a built in large filtration area.
> - An ongoing cleaning mechanism uses pressure to push out dirt    particles.
> - Mechanical root barrier prevents root intrusion
> - Anti-siphon mechanism prevents suction of dirt particles
> - Non Leakage mechanism keeps the water in the system once it is shut    and prevents uneven drainage
> - Membrane, structure and materials that withstand chemicals, acid and    extreme climate conditions

As I doubt that is as comprehensive an explanation as you were hoping for, and with "self-cleaning" in the context of pipes not having a widely accepted meaning, I fear your best choice may be to [contact](http://www.netafim.com/contact-us) Netafim for further details. They do show various 'connections' including Twitter.